# genhtml: ERROR: cannot read /Users/..../cover/Masonry/Masonry/MASUtilities.h

Tags: gcov, lcov

I put the. Gcno and. Gcda files in the cover folder and execute the command.
 `lcov --capture --directory cover --output-file coverage.info --no-recursion`

Errors encountered are as follows：
`Processing RFPushView.gcda geninfo: WARNING: could not open /Users/.../cover/Masonry/Masonry/MASUtilities.h geninfo: WARNING: some exclusion markers may be ignored Processing RFThemeConfigutation.gcda Processing UIView+RFThemeColor.gcda Processing RFThemeConfigutationS2.gcda Processing UIImage+RFExtends.gcda Finished .info-file creation`

Then I run the genhtml command `genhtml -o html coverage.info --show-details` and the error is as follows：
`Processing file /Users/lilong/.../cover/Masonry/Masonry/MASUtilities.h genhtml: ERROR: cannot read /Users/..../cover/Masonry/Masonry/MASUtilities.h`

I found that the RFPushView uses the masonry. If I remove the masonry from the RFPushView, lcov and genhtml will not report an error. But I definitely need Masonry. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are generating your .info files using the .gcda file in the same directory that the application was first compiled in.